# 3d markup on the forge viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I found this example (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card)
The code found in the link works fine but i would like to use a file/model in my private bucket on forge

1) I wondered if there is a way to access a file uploaded to the private bucket created on the forge platform ? If so , is it possible to access this file in the form of https://lmv-models.s3.amazonaws.com/toy_plane/toy_plane.svf like in this example ?

2) I edited the existing code to bypass the bucket and to load my onw model in the forge viewer and to add markups (the token and urn worked)

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=3.3" type="text/css">
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/three.min.js?v=v3.3"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v3.3"></script>
<div id="forgeViewer"></div>
<!--3D markup-->
<script src="markupExt.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var $ = function (div) {
return document.getElementById(div)
}

var options = {
   env: 'AutodeskProduction',
   accessToken: '$TOKEN'
};

var documentId = 'urn:URN';
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, onInitialized);

function onInitialized() {
window.devicePixelRatio = 1
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
const config3D = {
    'extensions': ['markup3d']
}
viewer.registerViewer(viewer.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D, config3D);
model = viewer.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoaded);
//viewer.loadExtension("markup3d");


function onDocumentLoaded() {
    var modelNodes = viewer.bubble.search(av.BubbleNode.MODEL_NODE); // 3D designs
    var sheetNodes = viewer.bubble.search(av.BubbleNode.SHEET_NODE); // 2D designs
    var allNodes = modelNodes.concat(sheetNodes);
    if (allNodes.length) {
        viewer.selectItem(allNodes[0].data);
        if (allNodes.length === 1) {
            alert('This tutorial works best with documents with more than one viewable!');
        }
    } else {
        alert('There are no viewables for the provided URN!');

    }
    onSuccess()
}

function onSuccess() {
    initializeMarkup();
}
}
///////////markup/////////////////

var elem = $("label");

function initializeMarkup() {
// plaatsing van een punt
var dummyData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dummyData.push({
        icon: 0,
        x: Math.round(200),
        y: Math.round(190),
        z: Math.round(50)
    });
}


window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('newData', {
    'detail': dummyData
}));
}
window.addEventListener("onMarkupClick", e => {
//elem.style.display = elem.style.display == 'block' ? "block" : "none";
elem.style.display = "block";
moveLabel(e.detail);
console.log(e.detail.id)
if (e.detail.id == 20) {
    elem.innerHTML = `<img src="sen.jpg"><br>Sensor ` + e.detail.id;
})
window.addEventListener("onMarkupMove", e => {
moveLabel(e.detail)
}, false)

function moveLabel(p) {
elem.style.left = ((p.x + 1) / 2 * window.innerWidth) + 'px';
elem.style.top = (-(p.y - 1) / 2 * window.innerHeight) + 'px';
}
</script>
</body>
```

The model is loaded but the mark-up are not shown.(The markupExt.js is the code found on the example link)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something missed while pasting the code snippets. The resource code of this awesome example is put here (https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt), you can find the link at the bottom of that blog.

After downloading, you have set up a web server to host this project and navigate to http://YOUR_WEB_SITE_OF_THAT_PROJECT/docs on your we browser. You will see the airplane and markups loaded without any problem. Just tested it on my machine~

**==== Update regarding [Micheal](https://github.com/wallabyway)'s comment:**

Since the Viewer's length units used in the Airplane and the Revit model are different, you cannot take advantage of the `markup3d` extension directly without any modification.

The following code snippet is I used on the sample `rac_basic_sample_project.rvt` from [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html). The `dbIds` are the sun module panels and the positions of the markup points are the mid-point of sun module's bounding box.

```
const dbIds = [ 3873, 3903, 3909, 3910, 3912, 3913, 3918, 3919, 3924, 3925, 3930, 3931 ];
const model = event.model;
const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
const globalOffset = model.getData().globalOffset;
const fragList = model.getFragmentList();
const dummyData = [];

for( let i=0; i<dbIds.length; i++ ) {
    const dbId = dbIds[i];
    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
    let box = new THREE.Box3();

    instanceTree.enumNodeFragments( dbId, ( fragId ) => {
        fragList.getWorldBounds( fragId, box );
        bounds.union( box );
    }, true );

    const worldPoint = new THREE.Vector3(
        ( bounds.max.x + bounds.min.x ) / 2 + globalOffset.x,
        ( bounds.max.y + bounds.min.y ) / 2 + globalOffset.y,
        ( bounds.max.z + bounds.min.z ) / 2 + globalOffset.z + 0.5
    );

    console.log( worldPoint );


    dummyData.push({
        icon:  Math.round(Math.random()*3),  
        x: worldPoint.x, 
        y: worldPoint.y, 
        z: worldPoint.z
    });
}

window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('newData', {'detail': dummyData}));
```

Here is the result:
[image]

If you have another question about that extension, I would like to advise you to discuss with the author directly: https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/issues

Comment: Thank you  for helping. I tried the code on github but edited a bit ( i updated the original post) Maybe this will make my question more clear

Comment: Please make sure that corresponding JavaScript files of that extension is linked to your webpage.

Comment: I did using  <script src="markupExt.js"></script> and   <script src="app_al.js"></script> in the header. Is that the right way ?

Comment: This might be related to the positions of the dummyData you created, i.e. the x, y, z values might not be proper for your model.

Comment: The example with the airplane works fine the problem is that i can't apply the markup to another model. I don't know if that is related to those values ?

Comment: The toy-plane, dummy points, is at a typical 'tiny' scale and 0,0,0 origin, which is typical for a Fusion/Inventor type model.  If your model is Revit, then make the dummy point range 100x bigger, and check the global-offset, it's probably miles away.

Comment: Update my answer above regarding Micheal's comment

Comment: Hi do you know how we can add `Markup Comment` at the bottom just like this thanks: https://boranora3.autodesk360.com/g/shares/SH919a0QTf3c32634dcffbc8ab8354b3fdd3

Comment: Unfortunately, it's Fusion Team/BIM360 only feature. Here is a similar example: https://forge-showroom.autodesk.io/post/3d-markup-with-multi-icons-and-info-card